# How to disable touch-pad without typing AutoHotKey?

Tags: node.js, electron, autohotkey

I saw many code in **AutoHotKey** to block the touch-pad while typing but now I want to block **touch-pad** without typing anything like when I run the format file AHK, it will be block touch-pad by using **AutoHotKey** tool. So if you know the code or way to disable it please help me out this that.
here is my current code:

```
; Script Function:
;       Disables trackpad for 500ms any time a key is pressed (prevents accidental mouse clicks)
;

#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

;keyboard hook code credit: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-127490.html#127490
#Persistent
OnExit, Unhook

hHookKeybd := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL   := 13, RegisterCallback("Keyboard", "Fast"))
Return

ReenableTrackpad:
BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
Return

Unhook:
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHookKeybd)
ExitApp

Keyboard(nCode, wParam, lParam)
{
   Critical
   If !nCode
   {
      BlockInput, MouseMove
      SetTimer, ReenableTrackpad, 500
   }
   Return CallNextHookEx(nCode, wParam, lParam)
}

SetWindowsHookEx(idHook, pfn)
{
   Return DllCall("SetWindowsHookEx", "int", idHook, "Uint", pfn, "Uint", DllCall("GetModuleHandle", "Uint", 0), "Uint", 0)
}

UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook)
{
   Return DllCall("UnhookWindowsHookEx", "Uint", hHook)
}

CallNextHookEx(nCode, wParam, lParam, hHook = 0)
{
   Return DllCall("CallNextHookEx", "Uint", hHook, "int", nCode, "Uint", wParam, "Uint", lParam)
}
```

Comment: Would you post the code you found? We may be able to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code. It appears that it is blocking **all** mouse input, including from a regular mouse. As it is, this probably isn't something you'd want to have to toggle on and off... or is it? Usually, laptops with touchpads have a key or key-combination that will disable the touchpad (something like Fn + F10).